# Python CSV needs to be re-read in before each "dict" operation

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm using the csv DictReader to read in a csv file and perform dict operations with it. The weird thing  is, that before each operation, I need to re read the csv file. Why is this the case?

```
import csv
readin = open("minimal.csv", "r")
dict = csv.DictReader(readin, delimiter=",", quotechar="\"")
for rows in dict:
   print rows
```

output:

```
{'Title1': 'One', 'Title2': 'Two', 'Title3': 'Three'}
{'Title1': 'Four', 'Title2': 'Five', 'Title3': 'Six'}
```

if i perform the print operation a second time:

```
for rows in dict:
   print rows
```

it returns nothing, not even an error. I need to perform steps one and two ("open" and "csv.DictReader") again in order to get the print output again. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work the second time is that the file pointer is already at the end of the file, so there is nothing to read; your reader object has already reached the end of the file.

By the way, don't use `dict` as a variable name, it shadows the built-in `dict()` function.

You can store all the rows in a list, so that you don't have to read the file again:

```
with open('minimal.csv', 'r') as readin:
    reader = csv.DictReader(readin, delimiter=',', quotechar="\"")
    rows = list(reader)

for row in rows:
   print(row)
```

Comment: Thanks alot my friend, that was a great help!